# vsftpd local users error "Incorrect login"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, user-management, vsftpd

I want to integrate an Android app with a FTP server, in this case vsftpd (My computer is running LinuxMint 18, kernel 4.4.8).

Anonymous users work, my user works (darijan), but I made another user (ftpuser1), set root directory to /srv/ftp/ftpuser1 (/srv/ftp is the default folder for vsftpd). When I try logging in with ftpuser1, the FTP server says 'incorrect password'.

My guess is that the ftpuser1's password stored on the ftp is the same on the local user, since that is the case with my main user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.) Add User with:  (This won't change anything in Ubuntu but just in case.)

`sudo deluser ftpuser1
 sudo adduser ftpuser1
 sudo nano /etc/passwd` - Change the path if needed

2.) In `vsftpd.conf` change `pam_service_name=vsftpd` to `pam_service_name=ftp`

Comment: It seems to be a bad idea to replace `vsftpd` with `ftp`, see : https://askubuntu.com/a/766379.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if you have enable these two options:

```
local_enable=YES   #Permit local user login
write_enable=YES   #Write permissions
```

Comment: i do have them set like that